# Finite fiber of universal covering

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Suppose that $Z$ admits a universal covering $\pi:Z'\to Z$. Show that $\forall z\in Z$, $\pi^{-1}(z)$ is a finite set.

Comment: Better not, there are spaces whose universal covering has infinitely many sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not necessarily true. The map $\pi : \mathbb R \to S^1$ defined by $\pi(t) = (\cos(2\pi t), \sin(2\pi t))$ is a universal covering of the circle, yet $\pi^{-1}(\{(0, 0)\}) = \mathbb Z$ is not finite.

Comment: I have a further question. If $Z$ admits a universal covering and we have covering maps $q:X\to Y$ and $r:Y\to Z$, how to show that $p=rq$ is a covering map?